# Basic style file upload input and make disabled input clickable with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to customize how the file upload look and i have something like this on [bootly](http://www.bootply.com/T4YzD04GLm)

it looks and works perfectly if i am using the upload btn but i also want the input to be clickable to upload- same action as the bt .. without changing markup

```
  <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Click Here" disabled="disabled">
```

jquery is fine version 2+

Comment: use a label tag with for attribute to point to the file upload button.

Comment: @dandavis without changing the markup with js

Comment: oh, then the answer's no; file input's must be clicked by the user in order to choose a file.